# Calculating values in a for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop that is storing values. For some reason, it is calculating values for all the number up to and including those in the for loop, instead of just the ones in the array.

```
t = 3600:50:172800;x = 0.1;y = 0; ro = 0.1;

T = zeros(1,length(t));

for Cm = 1E6:1E6:4E6
    for i = 1:length(t)
        T = T_ILS(x,y,ro,Cm,t);
        Tall(Cm,:) = [T];
    end
end
```

The error I get is "Requested 2000000x3385 array exceeds maximum array size preferences". I would like the for loop to calculate just the Cm values and not every number in between.

Comment: What is the variable `t`?

Comment: Added, cut out some of the code to keep it simple.

Comment: The line of code that you added is misplaced.

Comment: What does T_ILS do? Maybe you meant to use `T = T_ILS(x,y,ro,Cm,t(i));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not computing every value in between, but your indices are messed up. `Cm` takes values in the millions, but you use it to index `Tall(Cm,:)`. You probably want

```
t = 3600:50:172800;x = 0.1;y = 0; ro = 0.1;

T = zeros(1,length(t));

Cm = 1E6:1E6:4E6;
for j = 1:length(Cm) 
    for i = 1:length(t)
        T(i) = T_ILS(x,y,ro,Cm(j),t(i));
    end
    Tall(j,:) = [T];
end
```

Notice that the main function call assigns to `T(i)` and uses `t(i)` in the function arguments to justify the existence of the `for` loop.

Comment: On the inner loop, the same output value is returned `length(t)` times, before `Cm` actually changes.

Comment: Good point. Removed downvote from yours. I think you want `T(i) =... `

Answer (score 1):

In the inner loop, `T` is the output of the function `T_ILS`, using the same arguments each time.

```
for i = 1:length(t)
    T = T_ILS(x,y,ro,Cm,t);
    Tall(Cm,:) = [T];
end
```

I don't know what this function computes, but you probably wanted to do this instead

```
for i = 1:length(t)
    T = T_ILS(x,y,ro,Cm,t(i));
    Tall(Cm,:) = [T];
end
```

to account for each value of the vector `t`, or even better:

```
for t = 3600:50:172800
    T = T_ILS(x,y,ro,Cm,t);
    Tall(Cm,:) = [T];
end
```

**EDIT**: Also, to make this answer complete, I'd like to merge @MadPhysicist's answer with mine. The result would be

```
Cm = 1E6:1E6:4E6; x = 0.1;y = 0; ro = 0.1;

T = zeros(1,length(t));


for i = 1:length(Cm) 
    for t = 3600:50:172800;
        T = T_ILS(x,y,ro,Cm(i),t);
        Tall(i,:) = [T];
    end
end
```

Comment: Not same arguments. Cm changes. Assignment index is messed up.